# Generate swagger routes based on json schema

Tags: swagger, jsonschema, swagger-2.0

I have just a `restrul api`(I cant add swagger doc to my api) and my `json data model` shcema.
I want to be able to generate a client based on my `json data model` schema so I can talk to my `restful api` from my app.

How can you generate swagger client routes based on shema?
Say I have such simple schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "house": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how can I generate/add `get/put/delete` swagger routes to my schema so then I can generate a proper client for my `restful api`?